# Flow error, A record with these key values already exists

Tags: power-automate, common-data-service

I created a Flow where if a record is created in Common Data Service it will delay for 10 seconds an email containing the information from the record just entered. I had everything working up until I decided to make the email format a little better looking, deleted some dummy data I had entered and now it pops up this error in Flow:

> The request failed. Response content: '{"status":412,"message":"A record with matching key values already exists.","source":"org50841ab4.crm.dynamics.com","errors":[],"debugInfo":"clientRequestId: dbdfdece-dad5-431e-abd7-ede83be8bdf2"}'.

From what I can tell the record is entered into Common Data Service just fine but I receive the same error every time. Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any alternate key configured? Maybe somehow dummy data Id conflicts with new record like some auto-sequence number. Or read this: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Using-Get-Record-Action-in-Common-Data-Service/td-p/265408

Comment: @ArunVinoth - I don't have another auto number key or anything although I do have a primary field and primary image under the same entity. I wonder if that might have something to do with it?

Comment: Please don’t use the flow tag (the tag info says that). Can you find a better tag instead? For example facebook-flow or microsoft-flow.

Comment: I've had the same error for a flow that has been working for weeks and now all of a sudden has this behavior. I'm really baffled with how unstable Microsoft Flow is, and how noone seems to care about it.